# How can I use Nunit 3 to generate some test results after execution has finished?

Tags: report, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am using Nunit 3 with Nunit 3 Test adapter. How can I can a reporting xml file like Nunit-result.xml after executing using the Test explorer. I am using Unit Test Project (.NET Framework). My main goal is to get the Nunit report so I can configure and publish in Jenkin Job.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is possible when you use Test Engine API and get result from tests.
For more info about engine - https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Engine-API

When you run your tests in TestEngine you will get xml result and you can save like this:

```
IResultService resultService = services.GetService<IResultService>();        
        var resultWriter = resultService.GetResultWriter("nunit2", null);

resultWriter.WriteResultFile(nodes, "yourpath/TestResults.xml")
```